# Why can I not instantiate this global as a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, global-variables

My source file appears to give me an error of which I can't quite understand *why* it is I'm getting this error, as it appears to be somewhat in vain. What I'd also like to understand is what I can do about this to achieve the same effect. I'll leave out the details for now, but as is shown I would like for this to be a global object pointer.

**Code**

```
#include "functions.h" 

App::Game* game = new Game;

void display_func() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    game->render_objects();
    glFlush();  
}

void init(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    game->init_window();
    glutDisplayFunc(display_func);
    game->init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

**Compiler Error**

```
functions.cpp:3:23: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Game’
functions.cpp:3:23: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘App::Game*’ in initialization
```

I know I can't initialize this in the header file, so what options do I have?

Comment: Making a monostate huh?  Are you sure that the engine knows what App:Game is at this point from the header?

Comment: What is "App" and does it have a nested type of "Game"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write

```
 App::Game* game = new App::Game;
```

(with `App::Game` instead of `Game`).

---

**Edited to add:** Oh, I should probably explain the error-messages, for the sake of other people getting similar messages for a different reason. They're mostly self-explanatory, once you have the following facts:

- A "type-specifier" is something that denotes a type, such as `int` or `char*` or `string` or `std::string`; in this case, the type-specifier that you needed was `App::Game`.
- "Error: expected *X* before *Y*" *sounds* like it means that *Y* is fine, as long you insert an *X* before it; but in fact, it actually isn't saying anything about *Y*, except perhaps that it's not an *X*. "Before *Y*" mostly just helps you find where in the line the parse-error occurred. (In many cases it really is that something is needed before *Y* — for example, if *X* is a semicolon, then there's a good chance you dropped the semicolon after a statement or declaration — but in many cases it's actually that something is needed instead of *Y*. That was the case here.)
- `int` gets mentioned just because the compiler, scrambling to come up with a type-specifier in the hopes of continuing parsing, chooses `int` as a default. (Had you written `int *game = new;`, you wouldn't have gotten that second error message.)

Comment: +1.  Depending on the required lifetime for `game`, it may also be possible to use `Game game;` (on the stack) but then the `game->xxx` calls later would need to be changed to `game.xxx`.